# Select the correct record in an <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy>

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here - if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

I have the following associations in my application:

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :notificationable, polymorphic: true
end


class AccessPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    has_many :notifications, as: :notificationable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In one of my controllers, I have a call that finds all Access Permissions that belong to a project, and then select all the notifications for that collection of Access Permissions. But I'm having a bit of trouble. I thought a call like `AccessPermission.where(project_id: 1).notifications` would work, but it doesn't. So I resorted to doing this in ruby using `.map`

```
if AccessPermission.where(project_id: 1).map(&:notifications).include?(Notification.where(recipient_id: 1))
            
    #Here is where I need help. Find the notification record in the ActiveRecord::Associations that made the call above "True." I tried:
     notification = AccessPermission.where(project_id: 1).map(&:notifications).find(Notification.where(recipient_id: 1)).first

    ## That did not work, it returns an enumerator and then selects the very first object of the array no matter what the recipient_id is

else
            
    #create the notification if no notification exists
    access_permission.create_notification(recipient_id: 1)
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain this also is a terrible way to find the record, and won't scale at all. If someone has a better way to help me make this call in SQL, that's probably way better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a has_many through relationship on your Project model.

Something like:

```
  has_many :notifications, through: :access_permissions
```

Then you can just do

```
  project.notifications
```

to get what you want. Should scale pretty well, it will join the tables for the query.

After you have that you can do something like this:

```
project = Project.find(1)

if (notification = project.notifications.find_by(recipient_id: 1))
  # Do something with your notification here
else
  access_permission.create_notification(recipient_id: 1)
end
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for the reminder about has_many through!

Comment: I changed the notifications.find to a notifications.find_by call, which should be faster and avoid looping in Ruby.